# Auto submit image form when internet is avaiable

Tags: javascript, html, forms, offline

I am trying to make an offline HTML5 application that submits a form containing a image and a text input for a email address, **when a internet connection is avaiable**

This is what I have tried:

```
<body>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function () {
                function submit() {
        setInterval(function () {
            if (navigator.onLine) {
                //if internet is avaiable do:
                document.getElementById("upload").submit();
            }else {
                //if no internet
                var theDiv = document.getElementById("message");
                                    var content = document.createTextNode("No internet");
                                    theDiv.appendChild(content);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
            }
    </script>
    <form action="post.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="upload">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded" accept="image/*" capture><br>
    <p>Skriv inn din epost: <input type="text" name="email"></p>
    <input type="submit" value="Send ditt bilde!" name="sendimg" onclick="this.value='Submitting ..';this.disabled='disabled'; submit();">
    <div class="message"></div>
```

Does someone have any suggestions? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried attach listener in other way than `onclick`?

Comment: The internet is always available. Perhaps the internet connection might not be.

Answer (score 0):

Thee two ways to check this

This solution requires jQuery

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    timeout: 1, // Microseconds, for the laughs.  Guaranteed timeout.
    error: function(request, status, maybe_an_exception_object) {
        if(status == 'timeout')
            alert("Internet connection is down!");
    }
});
```

And

```
window.navigator.onLine -- it will be false if the user is offline.
```

You need to use above in your code with some tweaking as per requirement.

Comment: Milliseconds I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but i cant comment yet. Will this work?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
window.onload = function () {
            function submit() {
    setInterval(function () {
        if (window.navigator.onLine == "true") {
            //if internet is avaiable do:
            document.getElementById("upload").submit();
        }else {
            //if no internet
            var theDiv = document.getElementById("message");
                                var content = document.createTextNode("No internet");
                                theDiv.appendChild(content);
        }
    }, 1000);
}
        }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of continuous checking for Internet connection, you can use online and offline events. For reference see this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Online_and_offline_events. If the user is offline, save the data in local storage and then resend the data once the online event is again detected.